# Restoration of system image causes STOP 0x07B BSOD

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox, bsod, clonezilla

I restored a Windows 7 Clonezilla image of a Dell laptop I had to a virtualbox hard drive. During the boot process, I get a BSOD, [image: BSOD Error] I've tried repairs using both the internal system repair and using a Windows installation CD. I've run chkdsk and bootrec as well with no success. Booting in safe-mode hangs at classpnp.sys. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check for viruses as it suggests? You make no mention.

Comment: If Safe mode shows "classpnp.inf" during the startup list, it means it loaded it successfully -- it's hanging/crashing on whatever is after that.  7B is a hard drive/controller error ("INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE"), ensure you have the right VB HDD controller drivers installed into the Windows image you're trying to boot - this is not always easy.  There is tons of info about moving Windows between computers with dissimilar hardware, which is what you've done, so you should look up how to do that.

Comment: The machine that I am copying from has never had access to the internet and anything that has gone onto it has been scanned and verified. If it has a virus, I have bigger problems. (I am sure it is not a virus, and am more sure it is related to transferring to dissimilar hardware)

Comment: Hm.. That seems helpful, however, through creating a system image, I'm not looking to disconnect the hardware, but getting a snapshot of the current state so I can have a virtual test machine before implementing on the real system.

Comment: Did you even bother to sysprep this system?

Comment: Wouldn't that make changes to my existing configuration on the Dell machine(as I just want to copy the current system, not modify it)?